# How to debug an error when I create a string in login method?

Tags: android

[image]

> 03-30 23:49:56.536 15105-15105/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
>   03-30 23:49:56.560 15105-15111/? E/jdwp: Failed writing handshake
>   bytes: Broken pipe (-1 of 14) 03-30 23:49:56.560 15105-15111/?
>   D/dalvikvm: Debugger has detached; object registry had 0 entries 03-30
>   23:49:56.600 15105-15105/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method
>   android.view.Window$Callback.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts, referenced
>   from method
>   android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts
>   03-30 23:49:56.600 15105-15105/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve
>   interface method 21845:
>   Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts
>   (Ljava/util/List;Landroid/view/Menu;I)V 03-30 23:49:56.600
>   15105-15105/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002 03-30
>   23:49:56.604 15105-15105/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class
>   referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;) 03-30
>   23:49:56.604 15105-15105/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method
>   android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method
>   android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested 03-30
>   23:49:56.604 15105-15105/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve
>   interface method 21847:
>   Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested
>   (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z 03-30 23:49:56.604 15105-15105/?
>   D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002 03-30 23:49:56.604
>   15105-15105/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method
>   android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced
>   from method
>   android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
>   03-30 23:49:56.604 15105-15105/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve
>   interface method 21851:
>   Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode
>   (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode; 03-30
>   23:49:56.604 15105-15105/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at
>   0x0002 03-30 23:49:56.604 15105-15105/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find
>   method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations,
>   referenced from method
>   android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
>   03-30 23:49:56.604 15105-15105/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve
>   virtual method 502:
>   Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I 03-30
>   23:49:56.604 15105-15105/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at
>   0x0002 03-30 23:49:56.604 15105-15105/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find
>   method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method
>   android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType 03-30 23:49:56.604
>   15105-15105/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 524:
>   Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I 03-30 23:49:56.604
>   15105-15105/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0008 03-30
>   23:49:56.636 15105-15105/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.startActionModeForChild, referenced from
>   method
>   android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer.startActionModeForChild
>   03-30 23:49:56.636 15105-15105/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve
>   virtual method 22329:
>   Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.startActionModeForChild
>   (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
>   03-30 23:49:56.640 15105-15105/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode
>   0x6f at 0x0002 03-30 23:49:56.640 15105-15105/? I/dalvikvm: Could not
>   find method android.content.Context.getColorStateList, referenced from
>   method
>   android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getColorStateList
>   03-30 23:49:56.640 15105-15105/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve
>   virtual method 315: Landroid/content/Context;.getColorStateList
>   (I)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList; 03-30 23:49:56.640
>   15105-15105/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006 03-30
>   23:49:56.652 15105-15105/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method
>   android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method
>   android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable 03-30
>   23:49:56.652 15105-15105/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual
>   method 465: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable
>   (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
>   03-30 23:49:56.652 15105-15105/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode
>   0x6e at 0x0002 03-30 23:49:56.652 15105-15105/? I/dalvikvm: Could not
>   find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity,
>   referenced from method
>   android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity 03-30
>   23:49:56.652 15105-15105/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual
>   method 467: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity
>   (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
>   03-30 23:49:56.652 15105-15105/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode
>   0x6e at 0x0002 03-30 23:49:56.660 15105-15105/? E/dalvikvm: Could not
>   find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from
>   method
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
>   03-30 23:49:56.660 15105-15105/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve
>   instanceof 150 (Landroid/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable;) in
>   Landroid/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageHelper; 03-30 23:49:56.660
>   15105-15105/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x20 at 0x000c 03-30
>   23:49:56.680 15105-15108/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 234K, 22%
>   free 2639K/3364K, paused 1ms+2ms, total 9ms 03-30 23:49:56.692
>   15105-15105/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 31K, 21% free
>   2676K/3364K, paused 3ms, total 3ms 03-30 23:49:56.692 15105-15105/?
>   I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 3.506MB for 435468-byte
>   allocation 03-30 23:49:56.692 15105-15114/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC
>   freed 1K, 19% free 3100K/3792K, paused 3ms, total 3ms 03-30
>   23:49:56.700 15105-15108/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 3K, 19%
>   free 3097K/3792K, paused 0ms+0ms, total 6ms 03-30 23:49:56.700
>   15105-15105/? D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 5ms 03-30
>   23:49:56.700 15105-15105/? I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to
>   3.821MB for 333408-byte allocation 03-30 23:49:56.704 15105-15114/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 17% free 3422K/4120K, paused 4ms,
>   total 4ms 03-30 23:49:56.748 15105-15105/? D/libEGL: loaded
>   /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
>
> ```
>                                        [ 03-30 23:49:56.748 15105:15105 D/         ]
>                                        HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb85b25b0, tid 15105
>
>
>                                        [ 03-30 23:49:56.752    62:   62 D/         ]
>                                        Socket deconnection 03-30 23:49:56.756 15105-15105/? D/libEGL: loaded
> ```
>
> /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so 03-30 23:49:56.756
>   15105-15105/? D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
>   03-30 23:49:56.804 15105-15105/? W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib
>   not implemented 03-30 23:49:56.804 15105-15105/? E/OpenGLRenderer:
>   Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache 03-30 23:49:56.812
>   15105-15105/? E/OpenGLRenderer: Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from
>   Caches::initConstraints() 03-30 23:49:56.812 15105-15105/?
>   D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0 03-30 23:50:19.456
>   15105-15105/com.example.samsungvy277.myapp E/InputEventSender:
>   Exception dispatching finished signal. 03-30 23:50:19.456
>   15105-15105/com.example.samsungvy277.myapp E/MessageQueue-JNI:
>   Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback 03-30
>   23:50:19.468 15105-15105/com.example.samsungvy277.myapp D/dalvikvm:
>   GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 806K, 30% free 3127K/4428K, paused 5ms, total 5ms
>   03-30 23:50:19.468 15105-15105/com.example.samsungvy277.myapp
>   E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute
>   method for android:onClick
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
>                                                                                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
>                                                                                         at android.view.View.onKeyUp(View.java:7928)
>                                                                                         at android.widget.TextView.onKeyUp(TextView.java:5606)
>                                                                                         at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2647)
>                                                                                         at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:7343)
>                                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1393)
>                                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1393)
>                                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1393)
>                                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1393)
>                                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1393)
>                                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1393)
>                                                                                         at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1933)
>                                                                                         at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1408)
>                                                                                         at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2384)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:541)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:319)
>                                                                                         at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1860)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3791)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3774)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3429)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3398)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3483)
>                                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3406)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3540)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3429)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3398)
>                                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3406)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3429)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3398)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3516)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3666)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:1982)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1698)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1689)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:1959)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
>                                                                                         at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
>                                                                                         at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:132)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>                                                                                         at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>                                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>                                                                                         at an 03-30 23:50:19.468 15105-15105/com.example.samsungvy277.myapp
>   D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM 03-30 23:50:19.472
>   15105-15105/com.example.samsungvy277.myapp W/dalvikvm: threadid=1:
>   thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4c2e648) 03-30
>   23:50:19.480 15105-15105/com.example.samsungvy277.myapp
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for
>   android:onClick
>                                                                                       at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
>                                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
>                                                                                       at android.view.View.onKeyUp(View.java:7928)
>                                                                                       at android.widget.TextView.onKeyUp(TextView.java:5606)
>                                                                                       at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2647)
>                                                                                       at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:7343)
>                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1393)
>                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1393)
>                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1393)
>                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1393)
>                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1393)
>                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1393)
>                                                                                       at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1933)
>                                                                                       at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1408)
>                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2384)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:541)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:319)
>                                                                                       at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1860)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3791)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3774)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3429)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3398)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3483)
>                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3406)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3540)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3429)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3398)
>                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3406)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3429)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3398)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3516)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3666)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:1982)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1698)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1689)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:1959)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
>                                                                                       at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
>                                                                                       at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:132)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>                                                                                       at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>                                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Met 03-30 23:50:22.504
>   15105-15105/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 15105 SIG: 9

Answer (score 1):

Use findViewById after setting your setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)